# nuxtjs is blocking the loading of youtube videos by default or is it the browser?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, content-security-policy, nuxtjs

I have set:

```
render: {
  csp: false
},
```

in my nuxt.config.js but youtube videos are still being blocked by CSP?

is that a default browser thing?

Comment: Could you show CSP violation message from the browser's console? Default CSP can be published, for example, by Helmet middleware.

Comment: I see in the Dev Tool that HTTP header 'content-security-policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';` is published. I guess it's because Node.JS server have [Helmet](https://helmetjs.github.io/#reference) middleware installed. Check the `helmet.contentSecurityPolicy(options)` settings.

Comment: Ok I found it. Thanks grany. If you make an answer I will accept this as well. It was a line in my nginx config ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with nuxtjs but rather csp settings in my nginx config which overrode nuxtjs settings via http header injection.